# Cannot resolve import problem that are in the same directory

Tags: python

The purpose of this piece of code is to write the lyrics of my chosen song.. But I've been stopped by these syntax errors. Not too sure why it has happened.

MusicBot.py:

```
import Opening
import json
import requests
#Variables

artist = 'lil tjay'
song_title = 'Calling My Phone'
keywords = {'phone'}

url = "https://api.lyrics.ovh/v1/" + artist + "/" + song_title


response = requests.get(url)
json_data = json.loads(response.content)

lyrics = json_data['lyrics']



browser()
enter(lyrics)
```

Opening.py:

```
import MusicBot
import pyautogui as pg
import time

start = time.perf_counter()

def browser():
    pg.hotkey("winleft")
    pg.typewrite("opera\n",0.1)
    time.sleep(2)
    pg.typewrite("beep/n" , 0.1)



def enter(lyrics):
    pg.moveTo(-1267, 259 , 0.2)
    time.sleep(1)
    pg.click(-1267, 259)
    for i in range(5):
        pg.typewrite(f"{lyrics}\n")




finish = time.perf_counter()
pg.typewrite(f"Test 3 took {finish} seconds\n")
```

When I want to run MusicBot.py I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\amanm\Desktop\Python\Python Crash Course\Part 2\MusicBot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Opening
  File "c:\Users\amanm\Desktop\Python\Python Crash Course\Part 2\Opening.py", line 1, in <module>
    import MusicBot
  File "c:\Users\amanm\Desktop\Python\Python Crash Course\Part 2\MusicBot.py", line 20, in <module>
    browser()
NameError: name 'browser' is not defined
```

They are in the same directory:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DMkR.png)

Comment: That's a NameError, not a SyntaxError. You don't actually import the name browser.

Comment: try `from Opening import browser, enter` you need to import the function/class/variable which you are using in module first

Answer (score 1):

You need the format of `modulename.functionname` to call it from the module. In this case, `Opening.browser()`. The function has not been brought directly into the program, it's only accessible through the module. If you want to be able to access it directly, you could try `from Opening import browser`. Then you will be able to call `browser()` by itself. This is more efficient than:

```py
def browser(): Opening.browser()
```

The same applies for the `enter` function. To import both functions directly as part of the same statement, use commas to seperate the function/variable/object names: `from Opening import browser, enter`.

Even though the module is in the same directory, you must retrieve it similarly. If it was in a sub directory, you'd need to access it with the folder name before the file name (unless there is an `__index__.py` file).

Answer (score 0):

You can't call your function like that. Below is a simplified version of what to do.

**b.py**

```
def browser():
    return 'you have reached browser'
```

**a.py**

```
import b
print(b.browser())
#another option
#from b import browser
#print(browser())
```

**output**

```
you have reached browser
```